# Filling Empty Rows with Dictionary Values via For Loop Pandas

Tags: pandas, dictionary, for-loop, fillna

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

my_dict = {2078:'T20',2153:'T20',2223:'T21',2219:'T21'}

My data frame:

```
 Date        Code   Fleet   KM
  2021-20-03  2078   T20     20
  2021-21-03  2078   NaN     22
  2021-21-03  2153   T20     23
  2021-21-03  2153   NaN     23
  2021-22-03  2223   NaN     28
  2021-22-03  2223   NaN     30
  2021-22-03  2219   T21     23
  2021-23-03  2219   NaN     23
```

I want to use the values of the dictionary to fill the empty rows in the Fleet column in my df.

So I wrote the code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if (pd.isnull(row['Fleet'])):
    row['Fleet']= my_dict.row['Fleet']
```

However, when I check df.info() I can see that the code did not apply even though it runs.
Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: @jezrael I just updated with sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary and raplace missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['Fleet'] = df['Fleet'].fillna(df['Code'].map(my_dict))
```

Or [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df['Fleet'] = df['Fleet'].combine_first(df['Code'].map(my_dict))
```